# Custom mat-expansion with expansion icon after title

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a mat-accordion that has mat-expansion panels in for loop. The problem is, I need to do some customization like adding a checkbox in front of each expansion and the expansion icon should be placed after some specific text(in this case its book title). The alignments are a mess and as per my understanding, the expansion panels icon can be placed either at the end or beginning. As I think mat-expansion is the correct component to achieve the same. Need some guidance on how to achieve with mat-expansion or should I consider another approach?
[image: Before Expansion]

[image: After Expansion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try re-styling the `mat-accordion` for such a huge changes - it was designed to strictly follow material guidelines. Instead, create your own component based on `cdk-accordion` - basically it's a `mat-accordion` without any styles, so it gives you much more flexibility.

You can read the official docs (including examples of implementation) [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/accordion/overview).

Comment: Thnak you. Let me try with cdk-accordion